# My django models keep accepting values that they shouldn't

Tags: python, django, django-models

Ok so here's my model:

```py
from django.db import models

class PetSex(models.TextChoices):
    MALE = 'Male', 'Male'
    FEMALE = 'Female', 'Female'
    NOT_INFORMED = 'Not Informed', 'Not Informed'

class Pet(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    weight = models.FloatField()
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=PetSex.choices, default=PetSex.NOT_INFORMED)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Every time I try to add an invalid sex it should return an error but it keeep accepting it.

```py
>>> from pets.models import Pet
>>> petinfos_2 = {"name": "xamaria", "age": 1, "weight": 30, "sex": "Malasdasdde"}
>>> test123 = Pet(**petinfos_2)
>>> test123.save()
>>> test123.name
'xamaria'
>>> test123.sex
'Malasdasdde'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're facing is related to the validation of the `sex` field in your `Pet` model. Currently, you're using a `CharField` with `choices=`, but it **doesn't enforce the validation**.

One way to accomplish this would be to override the `.save()` method in your `Pet` model and manually check if the provided `sex` value is valid:

```py
class Pet(models.Model):
    ...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.sex not in dict(PetSex.choices):
            raise ValidationError('Invalid sex value')
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Now, when you try to save a `Pet` instance with an invalid sex value, it will raise a `ValidationError` and prevent the data from being saved.